# Delayed display of a UI control after execution of ReactiveCommand

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui, rx.net

I have a reactive command `readCommand` that I execute based on a signal.

```
IObservable<Unit> readSignal = ...

readSignal.InvokeCommand(readCommand);
```

The result of the command is shown in a user control, let's say a `TextBox`.

I would like to place a `refresh button` next to the `TextBox` which when clicked invokes the `readCommand`. This button should not be visible when the the command is executing and then made visible after 5 seconds of execution of the command.

My attempt to display/hide the `refresh button` follows. `IsRefreshable` is linked to the `Visibility` property of the `refresh button`.

```
readCommand
    .IsExecuting
    .SelectMany(x => (x ? Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0)) : Observable.Timer(refreshTimeout)).Select(_ => !x))
    .ToPropertyEx(this, vm => vm.IsRefreshable, false, false, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
```

I think it is working fine, when the rate of emission of `readSignal` is slower than the rate of refresh (`refreshTimeout`). But clearly does not work if the `readSignal` rate is faster than `refreshTimeout`.

Comment: After your `SelectMany` try putting in a `.Switch()` operator. I suspect you have an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` that needs to reduce down to the latest inner `IObservable<T>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, it seems to be working correctly. The only change is `SelectMany` needs to be replaced with `Select`. `SelectMany` flattens it, whereas `Select` returns `IObservable<IObservable<bool>>`. I also solved it through following but your solution is elegant. Care putting it as a answer? so others have easy time finding it rather than depending on the comments here.             `readCommand.IsExecuting.Where(x => !x).Select(x => Observable.Timer(refreshTimeout)).Switch().Select(x => true).Merge(readCommand.IsExecuting.Where(x => x).Select(x => !x)).ToPropertyEx(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `SelectMany` you are turning an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` into an `IObservable<T>` by merging all of the inner observables - which means all of the the timers will fire leading to unwanted behaviour.

A `SelectMany` is effectively the same as a `Select`/`Merge` combo.

What you need is to just produce values from the latest inner observable produced. For that you need a `Select`/`Switch` combo.

Try this:

```
readCommand
    .IsExecuting
    .Select(x => x
        ? Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0))
        : Observable.Timer(refreshTimeout).Select(_ => !x))
    .Switch()
    .ToPropertyEx(this, vm => vm.IsRefreshable, false, false, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);
```